# OpenCart 3 + Journal 3, remove email field from guest checkout?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3, journal

I want to remove email field from checkout page for guest, I use **OpenCart 3** with theme **Journal 3**. So what I can do?

I've tried to call out it from **guest.php** but still not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just remove email field. A lot of system properties connected to email on checkout, although using journal3 makes more complicated extraction of email.

You can see what fields you can turn on / switch of in Journal Quick Checkout:

*Journal > Skins > Checkout*

---

**UPDATED**

To disable Email only for guests in Journal 3 Quick Checkout:

Go to */catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/journal3/checkout/register.twig*

Find

```
{# customer email #}

<div class="form-group required account-email">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-email">{{ entry_email }}</label>
  <input v-model="order_data.email" type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="{{ entry_email }}" id="input-email" class="form-control"/>
  <span class="text-danger" v-if="error && error.email" v-html="error.email"></span>
</div>
```

Adding a check, like for password `v-if="account === 'register'"`. New code is

```
{# customer email #}

<div v-if="account === 'register'" class="form-group required account-email">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-email">{{ entry_email }}</label>
  <input v-model="order_data.email" type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="{{ entry_email }}" id="input-email" class="form-control"/>
  <span class="text-danger" v-if="error && error.email" v-html="error.email"></span>
</div>
```

Now go to */catalog/controller/journal3/checkout.php* and find

```
    // email
    if ((utf8_strlen(Arr::get($this->request->post, 'order_data.email')) > 96) || !filter_var(Arr::get($this->request->post, 'order_data.email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
    } else if (($this->session->data['account'] === 'register') && $this->model_account_customer->getTotalCustomersByEmail(Arr::get($this->request->post, 'order_data.email'))) {
        $error['email'] = $this->language->get('error_exists');
    }
```

Replace with

```
    // email
    if ($this->session->data['account'] === 'register') {
        if ((utf8_strlen(Arr::get($this->request->post, 'order_data.email')) > 96) || !filter_var(Arr::get($this->request->post, 'order_data.email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
        } else if (($this->session->data['account'] === 'register') && $this->model_account_customer->getTotalCustomersByEmail(Arr::get($this->request->post, 'order_data.email'))) {
            $error['email'] = $this->language->get('error_exists');
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but anyway to make it not required . my clients most of them have't email

Comment: Sorry for my laziness on the first try. Updated the answer. Now it's works like your whant.

Comment: am sorry but i did it but still available for guest

Comment: Have you reload Journal 3 caches? There is a button on any Journal page in admin. Although clear twig/system cache from a dashboard. I have tested my solution and it works

Comment: yes sir i'v changed the both codes above and clear cash but still appear in guest

Comment: Can you send me a link on livesite?

Comment: here on comments  ?

Comment: Yes. Only on client side. Without any passwords. Just want to see something

Comment: www.danagifts.com

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the emntioned 3 steps you have to fix the sendmail funtion. One way is mentioned here in 2 more steps:

File: system/library/mail.php
Change:

```
$this->to = $to;
```

To:

```
 if ($to != '') {$this->to = $to;} else { $this->to = 'web-and-seo@itech.bg';}
```

Change web-and-seo@itech.bg to an e-mail that you will receive the confirmation instead of the customer.

2. Then remove the * from the mail field on checkout page

File: catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/journal3/checkout/register.twig
Change:

```
<div class="form-group required account-email">
```

To:

```
<div class="form-group account-email">
```

Good luck.